# How do you set copy mode from your screenrc?

Tags: gnu-screen, screenrc

I want to enter copy-mode by default from screen. Right now, I'm using `stuff` to start a server. I'd like to then enter copy-mode so I can just use the mouse to scroll up.

I can't just use `stuff "Ctrl-a ESC"` (even though `Ctrl-a ESC` entered from the terminal sets  screen mode just fine).

Is there a special character for `Ctrl-a` that I can stuff? (like `^M` for a return)

Answer (score 0):

The command I needed was... `copy`.